# Parsing Date from Formatted String in Java

Tags: java, date

I have a string with format "Mon Dec 03 00:00:00 IST 2012".  I want to convert this string into Date. Any  formats will do.

Comment: Thank You everyone for your quick response.

Answer (score 3):

can try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse("Mon Dec 03 00:00:00 IST 2012");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parse()` method of SimpleDateFormat class. Read the API documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).

Answer (score 2):

date format of your string-represented date is:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: It should be EEE instead of E

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SimpleDateFormatter`. You can find details about them here:

[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");`